# Para que serve o camando adb forward e como usá-lo?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber o que é o adb forward e como usá-lo. Alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 2):

Não tem muito o que dizer sobre `adb forward`, além do que esta na documentação: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports

Ele serve para encaminhar portas do host (seu computador, aonde esta executando o comando adb) para outras portas do "dispositivo" (celular ou emulador), assim terá uma porta do host acessivel por outra porta no dispositivo.

Por exemplo, se tiver um servidor HTTP do qual queira acessar no celular ou emulador, esse comando ajudaria.

Também existe o contrário/reverso, quando desejar acessar a porta de um dispositivo no seu computador deve se usar `adb reverse`, por exemplo:

```
adb reverse tcp:80 tcp:8000
```

Supondo que tenha a porta 80 no dispositivo/emulador/celular, ela ficará acessível no computador conectado na porta 8000.

O exemplo com HTTP é apenas um uso, isso nem é questão de programação, mas sim de redes e dispositivos, que claro pode ajudar em programação como também pode ajudar em outras questões, como sendo funcionalidade que precisem acessar portas de ambos lados (computador ou dispositivo)